# Change Source.fromfile().getLines delimiter in Scala

Tags: file, scala, delimiter

I need to change the row delimiter in getLines method,
actually default delimiter is ("\n" | "\r\n" | "\r") but I need only \n.

For example, in my string "xxxxx xxxxx \r xxxx xxx\n xxxxx xxxxx \r xxxx xxx" with getLines I obtain 3 lines, but i need only 2, is possible to change it?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation suggests, you can refine the behavior of `getLines` by subclassing `LineIterator`.

```
class MyLineIterator extends LineIterator {
  override def isNewline(ch: Char) = ch == '\n'
}
```

Comment: How to use `MyLineIterator` in `io.Source.fromFile("abc").getLines` ? Also how to import it ? Little full example appreciated :) Still quite new to Scala :)